# c# windows service debug in visual studio

Tags: c#, filesystems, windows-services, access-denied

I'm creating a windows service using C# in visual studio 2019. Ive used installutil to install the service on my development machine, its running under the local system account. To debug, Ive attached the visual studio debugger to the running service.  The service has to create a .csv file and save it to the local file system, however every time I try to access the file system from within debug in VS I get this error

"Access to the path 'F:\Output' is denied."

The directory exists, Ive tried adding full control to all accounts on my local machine for that directory (and sub directories), Ive even used 'Everyone' as a last resort, but nothing I do will allow me to write to the local file system.  Can anyone help me out ? I'm really stumped.

Im using Windows 10 64Bit pro
Im also running visual studio 2019 as admin

Comment: What is F:? Network folder? Mounted disk?

Comment: F is a local drive, Ive even tried mapping it to the 'C' drive and it still wont work

Comment: What account use the service? Maybe you can try TopShelf http://topshelf-project.com/

Comment: the service itself runs under the local system account, vs runs under the admin account. Is there an issue with debug permissions from the VS debugger ? Ive tried everything and nothing works

Comment: As a general principle with services, I always start with a console app project, and after debugging and testing, use the tested code in a service project app. Services are hard to debug.